# Passing shell variables in awk

Tags: shell, awk

I am using a command to extract logs from a log file and the command work when I run it via terminal

```
awk '/Aug 19/||/Aug 21/{a++}a; a==4{a=0}' daily_usage_report.log
```

this command gives me the data from Aug 19 till Aug 21. The log file looks like below -

```
Aug 19

Line1
Line2
Line3
Line4
Line5
Line6
Line7
Line8
Line9

Aug 19

Aug 20

Line1
Line2
Line3
Line4
Line5
Line6
Line7
Line8
Line9

Aug 20

Aug 21

Line1
Line2
Line3
Line4
Line5
Line6
Line7
Line8
Line9

Aug 21
```

But when I try and use the same command in a shell script and want to pass shell variables to awk, it does not provide any output. The shell script that I have written is -

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

echo "Please enter the Full Date [eg- Aug  2 or Aug 20]"
read -p 'From Date: ' d1var

read -p 'Till Date: ' d2var

awk -v var="$d1var" -v vari="$d2var" '/"$var"/||/"$vari" /{a++}a; a==4{a=0}' daily_usage_report.log

exit
```

Running this script does not provide me any output.

Please help rectify my mistakes.

Comment: paste your code into http://shellcheck.net and resolve problems flagged there, then update your Q please. Good luck.

Comment: corrected the syntax but still no output

Comment: This is arguably a duplicate of [How to use a variable as regex in awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29055534/bash-how-to-use-a-variable-as-regex-in-awk). Granted, the question there already assumes the biggest missing piece (the `~` operator).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

awk variables are a different beast than shell variables.

1. Don't put a $ sign before awk variables in the awk script.
2. Your dates aren't quoted in the regex conditions of your initial awk script, so don't quote them when they are variables. Double quotes inside the regex aren't going to work out in your case.

Instead try:

```
awk -v var="$d1var" -v vari="$d2var" '/var/||/vari /{a++}a; a==4{a=0}' daily_usage_report.log
```

Comment: Tried, still no output. Thanks for your suggestions. Had read some tutorials and then tried modifying the script. I am still a beginner in awk

Comment: Instead run: `awk -v var="$d1var" -v vari="$d2var" 'BEGIN{print var,vari}' daily_usage_report.log` and insure that the variables are being set correctly inside the awk script. That should just print out the two dates as input and may help troubleshoot.

Comment: Also, with the space in your two dates it may help to quote the variable assignment like: `awk -v "var=${d1var} -v "vari=${d2var}"`

Comment: This time only dates were printed Aug 15 Aug 16 was the output

Comment: `~` should be used to compare against a variable storing a regex

Comment: @CharlesDuffy That must be it. `awk -v "var=${d1var}" -v "vari=${d2var}" '$0~/var/||/vari /{a++}a; a==4{a=0}' daily_usage_report.log`

Comment: @JNevill, I don't believe you need `/var/` either (as that's syntax for *literal* regular expressions) -- should just be `($0 ~ var || $0 ~ vari)`, if memory serves.

Comment: awk -v "var=${d1var}" -v "vari=${d2var}" '($0 ~ var || $0 ~ vari){a++}a; a==4{a=0}' daily_usage_report.log command finally worked. Thanks  CharlesDuffy & JNevill for your effort in solving my problem. Please do explain ($0 ~ var || $0 ~ vari) and what is the purpose of $0~